# Apache .htaccess <IF> statement with multiple matches

Tags: apache-2.4

I've tried ||, OR without success, so what is the more concise way to write these two matches on the user agent in a single  statement?

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1'">
  Require all denied
</If>
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)'">
  Require all denied
</If>
```

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure you did not make any syntax mistakes?

Usage of `||` is done this way and it works fine:

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1' || %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)'">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

Reference for expressions in Apache HTTP:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html

Comment: This very works. The OR condition `||` must be within the `<If>` statement's double quotes  `""` as a single expression. E.g. `"something || something"`, not `"something" || "something"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp:

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ /Mobile/">
   Require all denied
</If>
```